# How to save from mercury editor to php database

Tags: php, jquery, editor, mercury-editor

I am developing a Content Management System with the mercury editor ( non rails ).
But the problem is that I don't know how to save the JSON string giving from mercury editor.

Here is the JSON string that is giving by the editor.

```
{
"get_title": {
"type": "simple",
"data": {},
"value": "skdhfzsd"
},
"title": {
"type": "simple",
"data": {},
"value": "This is a test page"
},
"content": {
"type": "full",
"data": {},
"value": "<p>What is this kind of page ?</p><p>Well this is my cool test page to try out different stuff.</p><p><a href=\"http://www.domeinz.nl\" target=\"_blank\">Woot</a></p><p><iframe style=\"width: 560px; height: 349px;\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/ixifxQ_MDu4?wmode=transparent\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"></iframe><br></p><p><iframe style=\"width: 400px; height: 225px;\" src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/22193086?title=1&byline=1&portrait=0&color=ffffff\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe><br></p><p>☃ ©</p><p><br></p>",
"snippets": {}
}
}
```

The problem is that I dont know how to save it to my save.php file and how to get the request.

Greets wouter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send this json string to a PHP file (it is basically an array).

The PHP file can then process the information and insert it into the database.

Do not be scared about the how to process the result. Try doing a print_r($_GET) or a print_r($_POST) and you will see in the php file the exact info that the editor is sending you.

The PHP file should be made to process the information in the exact same way that any other form send the info, that is the beauty of this editor.